# I can't access wifi on my laptop

Tags: drivers, wireless, lubuntu

I downloaded lubuntu distribution and set it on my laptop

problem is that I can't connect to any wifi's

so how to find which wifi driver is compatible with the driver of my laptop?

or maybe there's another problem?

**my laptop model is Lenovo S21e-20**

> Wifi adapter isn't damaged, it's working on windows

Comment: I can access my laptops internet VIA mobile's USB;

Comment: You've provided no details of what release you're asking about; and if it's a LTS it may help if you're specific as to which media you installed with (LTS releases have two stack options; with Lubuntu the installation media used dictates your choice of kernel stack).  Also if you've followed any wifi documentation such as https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide where the *Device Recognition and Operation* section/link is the most useful in getting solutions.

Comment: @guiverc sorry, for my inconpetence. i am using 20.04 realaise

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command `sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms` and reboot. You will need to use a wired connection or USB tether your phone's hotspot to do so.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is fixed.

The problem was with `dpkg`

I ran:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And now my problem is fixed.

Comment: Well done for fixing it.